# Can a wizard have more than one Alarm spell active at once?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can a character have more than one Alarm spell active at a given time?  There doesn't appear to be anything in the spell description to prevent it, and it's not a concentration spell.  Is there some general principle that would restrict this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

As you said, there is nothing in the description to prevent it, and it's not concentration. The only limit to the number of alarms you can have is time. As it's a ritual spell, slots aren't even a concern for a wizard, so it's really a matter of how many 11 minute periods you have to play with.